# Exibir no histórico o Status e quantidade de dias por Status

Tags: c#

Olá, Tenho uma tabela no sistema que registra os historicos de de um formulario de atendimento contendo o historico desse formulário o mesmo passa por alguns status.

- 1º quando e gerado fica status = "Em aberto"
- 2º Quando esta em atendimento o status fica em = "Atendimento "
- 3º quando for solicionado o atendimento status "encerrado"

Ou seja nessa tabela historico vou ter no minino três status de um formulário até ai tudo bem.

O meu problema é que nessa tabela tem dois campos de data
DTMUDANCASTATUS e DTSAIDASTATUS o primeiro salva  a data quando há uma mudança no status
e o segundo salva a data final .

O que preciso fazer e não estou conseguindo é listar esse histórico trazendo as duas datas e
quanto tempo o formulário ficou de um status para o outro. Assim o usuário vai saber quantos dias ele ficou  no status em aberto, quanto tempo em atendimento e assim ate encerrar .

Por enquanto só tenho um endpoint que retorna todo o historico  nesse endpoint que preciso adaptar para mostrar quanto tempo ficou de um status para o outro .

```
    public Task<List<Historico>> ObterByFormularioId(long formularioId)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Method GetAll HistoricoService");

            var historicos = _historicoRepository.GetQueryable(h => h.FormularioId == formularioId).ToList();
            
            
             return Task.FromResult(historicos.ToList());
        }
```

Fiz esse metodo que soma as datas para solucionar esse problema, porem tem como melhorar ele deixar mais curto mais enchuto .

```
private string MudancaDeStatus(Historico historico)
{
if (historico.DataSaidaStatus != null)
            {
var dtmudamcastatusb = Convert.ToDateTime(historico.DataMudancaStatus.Value);
                var dtsaidastatus = Convert.ToDateTime(historico.DataSaidaStatus.Value);
                TimeSpan datasubtracao = dtsaidastatus.Subtract(dtmudamcastatus);

                return $"{Convert.ToInt32(datasubtracao.TotalDays)} dias, {datasubtracao.Hours} horas e {datasubtracao.Minutes} minutos";
            }
            else
            {
                if (historico.DataSaidaStatus == null) { }
                var dtmudamcastatus = Convert.ToDateTime(historico.DataMudancaStatus.Value);
                var dtsaidastatus = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan datasubtracao = dtsaidastatus.Subtract(dtmudamcastatus);
                
                return $"{Convert.ToInt32(datasubtracao.TotalDays)} dias, {datasubtracao.Hours} horas e {datasubtracao.Minutes} minutos";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Criei o metodo acima para o problema descrito porem alguma consegue me orientar como posso deixar ele mais enchuto

Comment: Só queria entender porque deram downvote na sua pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular tempo de uma data até a outra, você pode criar um método de extensão, por exemplo:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{ 
   public static string CalcTime(this DateTime HoraIni, DateTime HoraFim)
   {
       TimeSpan ts;
       ts = HoraIni - HoraFim;
       return ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
   }
}
```

Ai para poder usar, basta

```
historicos.DataMudancaStatus.CalcTime(DataSaidaStatus)
```

Ou também fazer o método de extensão retornar um TimeSpan,

```
public static TimeSpan CalcTime(this DateTime HoraIni, DateTime HoraFim)
{
   TimeSpan ts;
   ts = HoraFim - HoraIni;
   return ts;
}

historicos.DataMudancaStatus.CalcTime(DataSaidaStatus).TotalHours
```

Obs. pelo que endentedi, sua DataMudancaStatus é do tipo string? se for, recomendo fortemente que utilize o formato DateTime, até mesmo para consultas no banco de dados e manupulações.